# PHP MYSQL insert doesn't work and receive no error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have this PHP code , and i would insert a data in a table.
I don't know why , it doesn't work. I receive no error from the query.
If i print the `$update_miner` nothing is showed.
This is the code:

```
<?php


session_start();
include("header.php");
$building['rock_miner'] =3;
$current_time = time();
$update_miner = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `updates_queue` (`user_id`,`content`, `start_at`,`end_at`,`finished`,`old_level`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['uid']."', 'rock_update', '".$current_time."','".$current_time."',0 ,'".$building['rock_miner']."'");




include("footer.php");

?>
```

This is the table:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of the page.  Also try adding `if($update_miner === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($connection)); }`.  If an INSERT fails, there's got to be a reason (and an error message).

Comment: he said me : syntax error at line 1. What? is the error in <?php ???

Comment: What did the *entire* message say?  Perhaps the error is in the included `header.php`?

Comment: it says anlo what i wrote :/ No the error is not in the header. I tried to remove it and nothing changed

Comment: Is that syntax error from PHP or MySQL?  Can you copy and paste the entire message (and edit it into the question)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing one parenthesis at last

```
INSERT INTO `updates_queue` (`user_id`,`content`, `start_at`,`end_at`,`finished`,`old_level`)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['uid']."', 'rock_update', '".$current_time."',
'".$current_time."',0 ,'".$building['rock_miner']."')")
                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but wouldn't use int to store a time.
Int only goes up to a certain value and then will fail-or just store the highest value it can. I think that might depend on your mysql version though.

The comment before is a good start and make sure you have connected to the database as well.

So your `$connection` isn't false.

Comment: my db is connected. I tried the query in the phpmyadmin and everything works. The problem is the query passed by PHP. I also removed the header and footer include. Nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried the previous comment 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); `
Will show errors - generally.
`if($update_miner === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($connection)); }`
Will show any errors.

Also might be worth a sanity check - are you connected to the right database, I generally have 2. 1 development,1 live. Check both (if you have them)

Comment: I wouldn't use INT to store time either, but both PHP and MySQL have functions that allow one to convert to/from a "Unix timestamp" value. Note that you can't use INT(9), however, as that would have overflowed in 2001. Using INT will fail in 2038, and using INT UNSIGNED will fail in 2106.

Comment: Yeah I like the unix_timestamp options, but I would store my time as a datetime